# Show details in Fancybox with Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts, fancybox

I'm trying to show detailed information from a Highchart in a Fanycbox when I click on a part of the pie-chart. I have the following script:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'pie'
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        showInLegend: true,
        point: {
          events: {
            click: function(me) {
              $(me).fancybox({
                'autoScale': true,
                'type': 'iframe',
                'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                'transitionOut': 'elastic',
                'speedIn': 500,
                'speedOut': 300,
                'autoDimensions': true,
                'centerOnScroll': true // remove the trailing comma!!
              }).click();

              $('a href=' + this.options.url).one('click', function() {
                myfunction(this);
                return true;
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Aantal',
      data: [{
          name: 'Not complete',
          y: 10,
          url: 'http://bing.com/search?q=foo',
          color: '##ed1b2e'
        }, {
          name: 'Complete',
          y: 10,
          url: 'http://bing.com/search?q=bar',
          color: '##35ce06'
        }]        
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

When I click on a part of the pie-chart a fancybox is opened with the text: "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."

How can I use the variable URL (i.e. http://bing.com/search?q=foo) and connect it to the click on the pie-chart.

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to display the content of url on click of chart in fancybox ?

Comment: Yes that’s it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you write `$(me).fancybox({..}).click();` - here you attach and immediately fire  click event to start fancybox. That is so awkward, if you wish to immediately start fancybox, then you simply have to use `.open()` method, for v2 it would look like this:

```
$.fancybox.open({
  href: 'https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/iframe.html', 
  type : 'iframe'
});
```

If you upgrade to v3, then replace `href` with `src`.

Keep in mind that websites (like bing.com, google.com and other) can refuse to be loaded into the iframe.